# Make some List Union in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, union

I have 3 lists which every one of them has some instance of following class:

```
public class Menu
{
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Menu> Childs=new List<Menu>();
}
```

I fill everyone of these list in code below:

```
public List<Menu> GetAvailableMenus(string[] roles)
{
    var adminMenu = new List<Menu>();
    var terminalMenu = new List<Menu>();
    var gaurdMenu = new List<Menu>();
    if(roles.Contains("admin"))
    {
        GetAdminMenus(adminMenu);
    }
    if (roles.Contains("terminal"))
    {
        GetTerminalMenus(terminalMenu);
    }
    if (roles.Contains("gaurd"))
    {
        GetGaurdMenus(gaurdMenu);
    }                       
    return adminMenu.Union(gaurdMenu).Union(terminalMenu).ToList();
}
```

my problem is Union action just concat these list and do nor merge them in order to remove redundant items.
does anyone has any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't overridden `Equals` or `GetHashCode` for your `Menu` class, so `Union` has no way (except reference equality, which won't work here) to know that there are duplicates. Implementing those methods in a sensible way will make your code work.

These links might help:

- [Guidelines for Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Some info on GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Alternatively, you can just pass in your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer` as another argument to the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Menu` class needs to properly implement `IEquatable<>` in order to determine whether two entries are the same or not. Otherwise `Union` will use the default equality, which will compare reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an equality comparer for Union then it will be able to merge and not just concat your lists

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx

---

Update - reading your question again I'm wondering if you also want the child menu items merged too. If that's the case, then I think you will need to write some logic to do this - I don't think there's any way of using the Linq Union operator to do this nested merging.